# Run a .bat file with CMDER

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmder

I have a .bat file that I want to run in Cmder not CMD

```
echo off
:begin
echo Select a task:
echo =============
echo 1) P1
echo 2) P2
echo -
set /p op=Type option:
if "%op%"=="1" goto op1
if "%op%"=="2" goto op2

goto begin

:op1
start cmd /k cd C:\Users\**\Documents\Projects\P1
cd C:\Users\**\Documents\Projects\P1
grunt serve

:op2
start cmd /k cd C:\Users\**\Documents\Projects\P2
cd C:\Users\**\Documents\Projects\P2
grunt serve

:end
```

I want when I click on the .bat icon to open Cmder and run commands and also open a new tab in Cmder like I did in cmd (`start cmd /k cd C:\Users\**\Documents\Projects\P1`).

Thank you in advance.

I found this but didn't help a lot:
https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/457

Answer (score 1):

Save your above code at `%CMDER_ROOT%\config\user-startup.cmd` and it will auto run with you start Cmder. The `%CMDER_ROOT%` folder will be where the Cmder.exe is.

Answer (score 0):

the answer to use a user-startup.cmd file didn't work for me, current day; however, I did edit the user_profile.cmd file to call my batch file and that worked.